# On the proof of the spectral theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Pick a normal $f\in\text{End}(V)$, where the characteristic polynomial $\chi_f$ consists only of linear factors.

I want to prove that there is an ONB consisting of eigenvectors of $f$. (The other direction also holds, but is here not of interest). I prove it with induction on $\dim V$. In the induction step I chose an eigenvalue $e_1$, $|e_1|=1$, of some eigenvalue $\lambda$, possible by assumption.

I get a decomposition $V=\mathbb{K} e_1\oplus(\mathbb{K}e_1)^\perp$, where each summand is $f$-invariant. If I can show that I can use the induction hypothesis on $\widetilde{V}:=\mathbb{K}e_1$ then I am done. But why is this possible? I have an endomorphism $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{V}\to\widetilde{V}$, $\widetilde{V}$ has lower dimension than $V$ but why consists $\chi_{\widetilde{f}}$ of linear factors and why is it normal?

Comment: Hint: The condition for normality can be written in the form: for all v in V ... what happens if you make V smaller?

Comment: Hint 2: extend $e_1$ to a basis of V, consider the matrix of f w.r.t. this basis and compute the characteristic polynomial with help of this basis - where do you see the char. polynomial of $\tilde{f}$ in this computation?

Comment: The normal issue is done. Thanks for the hint. For the second part: I can find a basis of $V$ of the form $(e_1, v_1,...,v_{n-1})$, where the $v_i$ are a basis of $\widetilde{V}$. If I cross out the 1st column and row I get the part that  corresponds to the char. polynomial of $\widetilde{f}$. But why it is made of linear factors?

Comment: another hint: how does it relate to the characteristic polynomial of f

Comment: Alright, we have a block diagonal matrix here, that is the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is to summarize the comments I made before into an answer which constitutes of a series of hints

1. Concerning the normality of the mapping $\tilde{f}$: can you write this condition in the form "for all $v\in V$ ... ". What happens with such a condition if you replace $V$ by a subspace?
2. What happens if you extend the eigenvector $e_1$ to a basis of $V$ and consider the matrix of $f$ with respect to this mapping? How can you use this matrix to compute both $\chi_f$ and $\chi_{\tilde{f}}$ and how are they related?

Comment: Please let me know if I should add more details to the answer!